# jq merge data from different objects

Tags: json, shell, jq

I’m trying to merge these objects (preferably appending arrays from common x values) and not having any luck. I realize this is a noop but it’s the closest thing to what I think I want that doesn’t error:

```
jq -n -rSC 'def data: {"a": {"x": "t", "y": ["a","b"]}, "b": {"x": "t", "y": ["c","d"]}, "c": {"x": "r", "y": ["a","c"]}}; data | .[] | reduce . as $item ({}; . + $item)'
{
    "x": "t",
    "y": [
        "a",
        "b"
    ]
}
{
    "x": "t",
    "y": [
        "c",
        "d"
    ]
}
{
    "x": "r",
    "y": [
        "a",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

Expected output would be:

```
{
    "x": "t",
    "y": [
        [
            "a",
            "b”
        ],
        [
            "c",
            "d"
        ]
    ]
}
{
    "x": "r",
    "y": [
        [
            "a",
            "c"
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is example code. What I’d really like is this merged:

```
gcloud compute snapshots list --project "foo" --format=json | jq -rSC '.[] | select((.sourceDisk | test("data-disk$")) and (.autoCreated | true)) | {(.sourceDisk | match("/([^/]+$)").captures[0].string): [.diskSizeGb, .name, .creationTimestamp]}'
```

I’m kinda good with any outputs from the gcloud command that allows me to have snapshot data for an instance under one object. But I’m hoping it’s pretty similar to my example data.

I’ve tried simple add, the above reduces, map/map_value

Comment: Are you looking for `def data: …; reduce data[] as $item ({}; . + $item)`? Can you post the desired output to the example?

Comment: Consider the "please show intended output given the stated input" seconded. Right now it's not clear what you're asking for -- you're showing us code, but then expecting us to infer what that code is intended to do _from code that is already understood not to accomplish the thing you intend_. (Showing sample output from `gcloud compute snapshots list` and manually-created desired output is an alternate route to get to a place where this is clearly answerable).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the actual names of `x` and `y`, you can address them directly (setting `.x` and appending to `.y`) using this `reduce`:

```bash
(reduce data[] as {$x,$y} ({}; .[$x] |= (.x = $x | .y += [$y])))[]
```

```json
{
  "x": "t",
  "y": [
    [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    [
      "c",
      "d"
    ]
  ]
}
{
  "x": "r",
  "y": [
    [
      "a",
      "c"
    ]
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_JFgmZcUbls)

---

Or use a more functional approach, and `group_by` the common field:

```bash
[data[]] | group_by(.x)[] | {x: .[0].x, y: map(.y)}
```

```json
{
  "x": "r",
  "y": [
    [
      "a",
      "c"
    ]
  ]
}
{
  "x": "t",
  "y": [
    [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    [
      "c",
      "d"
    ]
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fe5eD7ylMfn)

Comment: This works with the example data, but for some reason (even when slurping and building the objects as disk: .sourceDisk, info: [.diskSizeGb, .name, .creationTimestamp] I get separate objects

Comment: @sandboxcom Giving you a profound answer relies on verifying it against actual data. That's why you were [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76656017/#comment135149915_76656017) to provide some input and (its intended) output data. As it turns out, your example wasn't representative (enough). Please consider either updating your sample data or providing (a relevant excerpt of) your real data, because as of right now there's no way to relate your coding attempts (`disk: .sourceDisk, info: [.diskSizeGb, .name, .creationTimestamp]`) and your observations ("I get separate objects") to any data.